# Spacing top left right bottom of container

Tags: css

Hi guys I'm new and making progress in css design. I tried setting the border, margin, padding to 0 of container that has a gray background, but I can't remove the whitespace above, below, left and right. How do I remove it and stretch to fit the browser without extra white space on top, bottom left and right?

Here's what I have so far. Thanks :) http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/3yhRt/embedded/result/

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container {
    min-width:1024px;
    min-height:768px;
    background:#CCC;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#container2 {
    width:1080px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    min-width:1024;
}

#wrapper {
    min-width:800;
    min-height:600px;   
}

#header {
    width:900px;
    min-height:120px;
    background-color:violet;
}

#menubar {
    width:900px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:inline;
}

li {
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#;
    border-right:1px solid #CCC;
    float:left;
    padding-left:30px; /*adjust space of menu text to each other*/
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px; 
}

a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
} /* visited link */

li:hover {
    background-color:#ffd640;   
}

ul#mcolor li:hover > a {
     background-color:#ffd640; <!-- sets all link color when hovering to yellow  -->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: i added body {} now it's working. Is it the default tag?
Thanks A Lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body,html
{
min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ra_htial

I have updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/3yhRt/2/) for the same

Please refer and reply.